# How do I discuss the system of equations by a given parameter?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have to solve this by Cramer's rule I got the system of equations
$mx+y+z=1$, $x+my+z=m$, $x+y+mz=m^2$ ,
I got that $D=m^3-3m+2$, $Dx=-m^3+m^2+m-1$, $Dy=(m-1)^2$, $Dz=m^4-2m^2+1$ Then I got $D=0$ for $m=1$ and $m=-2$ for $D=0$ $m=1$ I got that system is not determined (has infinity solutions) for $D=0$ $m=-2$ I got that system is inconsistent
now D is different from $0$ for m different from $1$ and $-2$ so now I am having trouble should I just get some random values of $m$ ? I tried with $m=3$ and $m=0$ and I got solutions but if I get $m<0$ I don't get correct values so can I say that for $m>0$ and m different from one system has solution and for $m<0$ system has no solution or what ?

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CramersRule.html

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

If you factorize all the polynomials $D_°$ instead of just $Dy$, you get:
$$D=(m+2)(m-1)^2,\ Dx=(m+1)(m-1)^2,\ Dy=(m-1)^2,\ Dz=(m-1)^2(m+1)^2)$$
and you see that all the fractions $\frac{D_°}D$ simplify; thus for $m\ne-2$ it is:
$$x=-\frac{m+1}{m+2},\ y=\frac{1}{m+2},\ z=\frac{(m+1)^2}{m+2}$$
Of course the case $m=1$ is nothing but an extension by continuity.

Comment: `all the fractions D°/D simplify` But only if $m \ne 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative without Cramer:  adding the three equations gives:

$$(m+2)(x+y+z)=1+m+m^2$$

If $m=-2$ the system has no solutions, otherwise dividing by $m+2 \ne 0\,$:

$$x+y+z=\frac{m^2+m+1}{m+2}$$

Subtracting the above from each of the original equations:

$$
(m-1)x=1-\frac{m^2+m+1}{m+2} = -\frac{m^2-1}{m+2} = - \frac{(m-1)(m+1)}{m+2} \\
(m-1)y=m-\frac{m^2+m+1}{m+2} = \frac{m-1}{m+2}\\
(m-1)z=m^2-\frac{m^2+m+1}{m+2} = - \frac{m^3+m^2-m-1}{m+2} = -\frac{(m-1)(m+1)^2}{m+2}
$$

If $m=1$ then the system is undetermined, and the general solution is given by $x+y+z=1$. Otherwise $m-1 \ne 0$ cancels out in each of the above, giving a unique solution in $x,y,z$.